# Compare two dataset and add coulm in 1st dataset if exists in 2nd dataset

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two datatable :

```
table1:
id value label
1  val1  lbl1   
2  val2  lbl2 

table2:
id value label
1  val1  lbl1
```

I want to compare two datatable and add a column to 1st table  say 'assigned'= 'true' if it exists in table2 else false.

How do I do this? Either in c# or TSQL would help.

So the final result what I expect is:

```
    id value label assigned
    1  val1  lbl1   true
    2  val2  lbl2   false
```

here since id=1 exists in both tables it is marked as assigned and id=2 which is only present in table1 and not in table2 then it is marked as false in assigned column.

**EDIT**
I have two separate select queries to get table1 and table2 data:
Here are my queries:
**query1:**

```
select Id,label,Values from 
t1 inner join t2 
on ID=t2.UDF1ValueID inner join t3
on t2.UDFID = t3.UDF_ID
where ID=15
```

**query2**

```
select Id,label,Values from t4 w
inner join t2 on(w.Id=t2.Id)
 inner join t3 on (t3.ID=t2.ID) 
 inner join t4 on (t3.ID=t4.ID)
  where w_Id=5 and t2.ID=15
```

Comment: I do not think question is unclear as I have got 3 responses to my question. If it was unclear then no one would have been able to answer my doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `LEFT JOIN` with a combination of `CASE` statement:

```
-- Sample Data
WITH table1(id, value, label) AS(
    SELECT 1, 'val1', 'lbl1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'val2', 'lbl2'
),
table2(id, value, label) AS(
    SELECT 1, 'val1', 'lbl1'
)
-- Solution
SELECT
    t1.*,
    assigned = CASE WHEN t2.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @t table (Id int,val varchar(10),label varchar(10))
insert into @t (id,val,label)values(1,'val1','lbl1'),(2,'val2','lbl2')

declare @tt table (Id int,val varchar(10),label varchar(10))
insert into @tt (id,val,label)values(1,'val1','lbl1')


select tt.id,tt.val,tt.label,CASE WHEN  ttt.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END 'Assigned'
 from @t tt INNER JOIN @tt ttt ON tt.Id = ttt.Id
```

OR

```
 select tt.id,tt.val,tt.label,CASE WHEN  tt.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END 'Assigned'
 from @t tt  where exists (select 1 from @tt t where t.Id = tt.Id)
```

Answer (score 2):

C# way of doing.

> Please note this code here just handles schema but not data.

```
DataTable t1;
DataTable t2;

foreach( DataColumn c in t1.Columns)
{           
    if(!t2.Columns.Contains(c.ColumnName))
    {
        t2.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(c.ColumnName,c.DataType));
    }
}
```

Working sample can be found [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Lw3dkA)